# How to implement push in updateMany due to update deprecation warning?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've been trying to figure out how to update now that update is prompting deprecation warning and that I should be using either `updateMany` or `updateOne`.

Upon checking documentation, there is no `$push` for updateMany.

```js
  const { ok: studentsUpdated } = await Student.update(
    {
      _id: { $in: studentsIds },
    },
    {
      $set: {
        isArchived: true,
      },
      $push: {
        archiveHistory: {
          $each: [
            {
              adminId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(loggedAdminId),
              status: 'deleted',
              reason: reason
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    {
      multi: true,
    },
  );
```

Thanks for your input.

Comment: `updateMany` and `updateOne` should support exactly the same update operators. Where are you seeing that $push isn't supported for updateMany?

Comment: @willis in the docu, there is no "push" term https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/

Comment: See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/ for the list of operators

Comment: @willis, the update function is now part of the deprecation warning, and supposed to use updateOne or updateMany instead of update. With update there is no issue with push. In updateMany, I have yet to figure it out.